# In as/flex, Is it possible to find all Classes in a package that implement a certain interface?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

In as/flex, Is it possible to find all Classes in a package that implement a certain interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking about doing this programmaticly, you can use the flash.utils.describeType to get XML to show you the interfaces a class implements. However, you'd still have to know the name of the classes - because the 'discovering' the classes in a package is not simple.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the -link-report "outputLinkreport.xml" mxmlc command line option and parse the resulting XML file. This is an offline process.

Answer (score 0):

for me I will:

search *.as at the package root folder

then use editors like notepad++ to open all of them

and then search for the interface keywords in all files